# Why Byte [] gets converted to String in JSON view

Tags: java, javascript, json, spring-mvc, arrays

I am generating a JSON view using spring MVC  and one of the attribute in the java object is byte array

```
public class Profile {

private String profId;
private byte[] image;
....
}
```

I am setting up the spring view as json view

```
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("jsonView");
    Profile res = profService.get(profId);
    mav.addObject("prof", res);
    return mav;
```

I debugged and everything is fine till I return the mav ( it has the byte array[])

```
[-119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 99, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, -89, -124, -97, 57, 0, 0, 0, 1, 115, 82, 71, 66, 0, -82, -50, 28, -23, 0, 0, 0, 4, 103, 65, 77, 65, 0, 0, -79, -113, 11, -4, 97, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 112, 72, 89, 115, 0, 0, 14, -61, 0, 0, 14, -61, 1, -57, 111, -88, 100, 0, 0, 6, 86, 73, 68, 65, 84, 120, 94, -19, -101, -49, -53, -107, 69, 20, -57, -3, 15, 91, -75, 105, -43, -90, 85, 27, 87, 109, 90, -71, 40, 8, 114, -31, 66, 34, -56, 69, 65, 68, -32, 34, 34, -56, 69, -94, 89, -111, -46, 15, -92, -92, -92, -62, 34, 67, 43, -59, 8, 19, 17, 9, -5, -64, -9, 114, -18, -68, -49, 125, 102, -26, -52, 121, 102, 46, -49, -123, -28, 89, 120, 95, -26, -103, -7, -52, 119, -50, -100, 57, -25, -36, -71, -57, -98, 28, -26, -65, 99, -121, -119, -3, -28, 127, -18, -3, 46, -36, 88, -67, 111, -36, -66, -1, -19, -49, -9, -50, 95, -67, -11, -50, -59, 27, 60, 31, 126, -7, 27, 31, 121, -106, -49, -79, 63, -9, -93, -57, -1, 94, -70, -10, -5, -87, -9, -66, 123, -10, -28, 39, 79, -99, 56, 63, -5, 60, -13, -54, -57, -81, -98, -67, -58, 124, -18, -35, 127, 20, -101, 67, 103, 110, 20, -99, -32, 62, 119, -22, -77, 23, -33, -4, -38, -98, -25, 79, 127, -98, -50, -124, 9, -68, 127, -7, 87, -90, -38, 74, -33, -115, -5, -6, -51, -65, -113, -65, 126, -59, -104, -48, -5, -14, -9, 127, -26, -28, -92, -15, 107, 31, 92, 7, 90, -19, -103, 27, -115, -101, -48, -5, 112, 99, 24, 79, -65, 116, 65, 16, 47, -65, -5, -51, -51, 59, 15, 60, 16, -56, -100, -82, -49, 27, -25, 126, -16, -68, -91, 54, 29, -72, -33, -6, -24, 39, 17, -97, 120, -5, 42, 27, -47, 63, -74, 90, -2, -13, -16, 49, -38, -37, -100, -7, -24, -23, 97, 41, -73, 65, 99, 24, -98, -15, 114, 109, -80, 19, -83, 24, 59, -63, 99, -18, -117, -72, 49, 15, -23, -76, 16, 90, -109, -7, -22, -57, -69, 66, 71, -2, -86, 4, 113, 110, -10, -106, -122, -23, 2, 109, -24, 18, 2, 39, 83, 70, 15, 114, -77, -108, -14, 30, -40, 116, 85, -101, -90, 6, 28, 79, 116, -117, 34, 101, -41, 30, -28, 70, 15, 9, 19, -40, -120, -27, 105, -104, 34, 101, -9, 18, -31, -90, 107, 29, 46, -72, -68, 38, 45, -99, -115, -39, -93, 85, 81, 34, -36, -100, -49, -43, 126, -99, -120, -71, 102, 50, -62, -126, -28, 17, 110, 66, -117, 113, 98, 107, 38, -78, 67, -126, -126, -36, -60, -102, -71, 49, 18, -99, -49, -83, 39, 115, -45, 10, 48, -118, -106, -12, -113, -65, 30, -50, -66, -40, -52, -115, -5, 83, -113, -50, -125, -83, 9, 55, 109, 44, 83, 57, -5, -23, 47, 125, -72, -75, 105, -24, 52, 12, -28, 124, 17, -29, 46, -104, 120, -77, -34, 56, 62, 92, 44, 91, -45, 57, 124, -72, -103, 76, 60, -25, -78, -102, -71, -61, 28, -83, 47, -54, 107, -67, 112, -26, -117, 62, 118, -46, 58, 124, -72, -67, -72, 115, 46, 101, -19, 122, 19, 30, 30, -104, -34, -118, -112, 115, 65, -37, 122, -11, 102, 71, -62, 13, -3, -127, -23, 77, -46, 9, 119, -82, 104, -79, 82, -67, 117, -70, 113, 48, -25, 114, -97, -107, 114, 99, -42, -27, -32, 126, -115, -36, 100, 12, -54, -92, 10, 33, 80, -112, 91, -27, 50, 85, -49, 116, 124, -14, -111, -59, 13, 123, -21, -12, 69, -119, 93, 8, 6, 105, -36, -64, 77, 85, -124, -77, -105, -60, -52, 74, 37, 10, -80, -46, -121, 124, 66, 21, -97, -16, 4, -104, -65, 58, 44, 119, -30, -30, 38, 38, -111, 87, 74, 31, -12, 72, 11, 104, 105, -79, -118, 102, 120, 3, -78, -3, 86, 122, 98, 76, -71, -111, 106, -82, 93, -31, -90, 35, 101, 9, 122, -128, -61, 42, 114, 57, 37, 118, -119, -63, -92, -19, 89, 28, 127, -27, -110, -79, 52, 121, 22, -83, 26, 36, -105, -72, -79, 87, -51, 94, 113, -103, 63, 5, 38, -40, -89, 6, 34, 115, 2, -126, -62, 72, 85, 120, -90, 39, 104, 124, -97, 103, -96, 44, 55, -90, -84, -127, 65, -113, 85, -84, 65, -63, -112, 60, 28, 76, 76, -119, -74, -89, -79, 36, -104, -25, -74, -52, -105, -127, -85, 75, 86, -42, 50, -105, 104, -23, 45, -83, -116, -106, -108, 13, -29, 81, 58, -53, -35, 84, -17, -86, 26, -64, -92, 1, -25, 31, -96, -72, 38, -42, 80, -2, 78, 15, -69, -94, 73, -96, -87, -34, -12, -88, -76, 119, 68, 109, 4, 104, 118, -22, -60, 47, 97, -42, 1, -65, 57, -27, -106, -65, 99, -55, -102, 102, -17, 84, 125, -30, 76, -7, 24, 32, -98, -79, 19, 79, -95, -56, -119, 56, -37, 76, 22, -120, 40, -72, 118, 79, -79, -72, 48, -42, 17, -67, -11, -27, -53, 8, 11, 49, 2, -48, -53, 59, -43, -87, -53, -106, -37, 14, 88, -1, -90, 118, -114, 49, -94, -39, -106, 91, -2, -88, 122, -64, -114, -128, 8, -12, -71, -27, -106, -25, -33, 67, 97, 36, 64, -71, -5, -54, -122, 27, -37, -112, 123, 26, -31, 70, -70, -128, 78, 58, -39, 112, -53, -109, 112, -92, -113, 24, 99, 68, -97, 27, 110, 21, -75, 114, -59, -95, 17, 3, 47, -20, 115, -61, -83, 34, -30, 80, 15, -72, 16, 116, -34, 78, -60, 125, 40, -50, 100, 27, 15, 82, 102, -122, -69, -5, -105, 99, 125, 53, 78, 123, -37, -40, 73, -71, -120, 56, 110, -8, 112, -49, 27, 110, -114, 95, -123, -19, -31, -114, -10, -4, -30, -122, 27, -73, -83, -20, 38, -106, -38, -20, 25, 122, 107, -33, -4, -113, -44, 6, -18, 92, 29, 113, -1, 100, -27, 17, -73, -25, -68, 92, -8, -95, 28, 61, 91, 110, -5, 22, -8, 32, 66, -108, 35, -15, -73, 36, 39, -64, 90, 24, -44, -17, -63, -88, -114, 112, -101, -28, -98, 27, 32, 101, 56, 54, 58, 73, 13, 69, 34, -50, -32, -76, -84, -91, -37, 120, -2, 98, 80, 110, -108, 105, 126, 105, 21, -120, -80, -75, 16, -94, 105, -117, -105, 31, -46, -31, -40, 77, 54, -51, 100, -90, 126, -94, 51, 31, -73, -24, -87, 51, -91, 122, 64, -100, 86, 9, -39, -30, 116, -123, -64, 28, -58, -72, 87, 100, -26, -1, -4, 37, -67, -118, -121, 77, -58, -24, -25, -21, 62, 18, -116, 99, -56, 89, -101, 100, -35, -119, 37, 37, 48, 40, -128, -106, -81, -76, -111, 98, -126, 107, -109, -28, -107, -42, 26, -12, 60, 55, -42, 105, -123, 14, -126, -83, -14, 54, 5, -38, -86, 100, 16, 55, -19, 105, -84, 81, 37, 72, -106, -105, 5, -15, 111, -24, 82, 93, 83, 6, -93, 114, 74, -39, -36, 49, 0, -60, -117, 37, -22, -52, -45, 74, -72, -2, 83, -81, 82, 71, 6, -41, -18, -115, -54, 0, 88, 10, -42, 52, 119, 77, -63, 47, -40, -92, -91, 2, 82, -98, -22, -115, -80, -20, -66, -100, -12, 8, 40, 114, -18, 126, -57, -64, 31, -61, -108, -77, 47, -38, -99, 45, -113, 63, 112, 125, -33, -64, 48, 24, 49, -96, -109, 91, -71, 78, 109, -4, -45, 83, 45, 4, 127, 80, 117, -16, 94, 110, 27, 27, 35, 102, 77, -23, -102, -3, 20, 51, -24, -62, 52, -80, 117, -7, -91, -22, 93, -39, 102, 110, -115, -118, 127, -20, 14, -83, -98, 85, 17, 25, 117, 127, -48, -65, -12, -127, -106, 42, -37, -106, 99, -115, -96, -34, 1, 26, -1, 43, -86, 84, 34, 121, -95, 8, -75, 70, 110, 102, 40, -25, 91, 56, -83, 87, -54, 93, 45, -78, -82, -108, -69, 90, -9, 91, 41, -73, -18, 113, 96, -30, -34, -8, -37, -65, 123, -122, -74, -60, -55, -106, -21, -61, 43, -43, 27, 81, -60, -35, -19, -98, -23, 80, -103, -83, 115, 60, -96, -72, 115, 7, 126, -77, -34, 74, 41, -70, 71, 38, 19, 57, -20, 123, -124, 110, -10, -83, 88, -39, 31, 40, -57, -42, 71, 117, -65, 66, 49, -89, 89, 111, -3, -2, 32, 119, 29, 49, 70, -71, -5, 86, 117, -108, 102, 110, -117, 123, -122, 126, 19, -92, -88, -80, 96, -115, -51, -36, 104, -93, -116, 48, 92, -88, -88, -82, -119, 57, -63, 66, -56, 25, -31, -42, 13, -48, 113, 95, -86, 40, -15, 41, 95, 49, -113, 112, 123, -18, -55, 85, 69, -51, 53, 112, 118, 30, -31, 102, 72, -91, -6, 35, 110, -35, 59, 123, 14, 114, 91, 37, -79, -81, 67, -108, -5, -29, -87, -34, -17, 8, 114, 35, -71, 93, -6, 112, -42, -76, -86, -106, 99, 87, 118, -86, -55, 37, 93, -59, -71, 121, -39, 126, 75, 86, -107, -57, 3, 45, 55, -27, 60, 25, 22, 113, 67, 99, 87, 120, -106, 84, -126, 48, 15, 93, -114, 2, -35, 121, 44, 44, -27, -74, 61, 42, -49, -40, -102, -28, 67, 105, -65, 60, 109, -70, 59, -41, -127, 27, 116, -50, 32, 43, 104, 97, -99, -98, -33, 23, -29, -17, -16, -45, -10, -45, -24, -42, 111, 10, -6, 112, -85, -18, -111, 94, -5, -94, -78, -123, -11, -109, -103, -89, 115, 96, 53, -8, 11, -72, 105, 97, -65, -49, 125, -74, -22, 6, 42, 55, -128, 126, -9, -90, -99, 92, -37, -18, -61, -36, -62, 27, -70, -101, -34, -23, 124, -48, -107, 98, 118, 110, 2, 8, 92, 45, -20, 87, -27, 27, -62, 61, 25, 85, -26, -47, -9, -70, -39, 62, -72, -85, -30, 5, 26, 28, 42, -9, 127, -70, 49, -102, 79, -12, 30, -24, -86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 69, 78, 68, -82, 66, 96, -126]
```

But when I checked the JSON response on browser it got string instead of array

```
{
"prof": {
      "profId": "Test123",
      "image": "ODk1MDRFNDcwRDBBMUEwQTAwMDAwMDBENDk0ODQ0NTIwMDAwMDAzRDAwMDAwMDYzMDgwMjAwMDAwMEE3ODQ5RjM5MDAwMDAwMDE3MzUyNDc0MjAwQUVDRTFDRTkwMDAwMDAwNDY3NDE0RDQxMDAwMEIxOEYwQkZDNjEwNTAwMDAwMDA5NzA0ODU5NzMwMDAwMEVDMzAwMDAwRUMzMDFDNzZGQTg2NDAwMDAwNjU2NDk0NDQxNTQ3ODVFRUQ5QkNGQ0I5NTQ1MTRDN0ZEMEY1QkI1NjlENUE2NTUxQjU3NkQ1QUI5MjgwODcyRTE0MjIyQzg0NTQxNDRFMDIyMjJDODQ1QTI1OTkxRDIwRkE0QTRBNEMyMjI0MzJCQzUwODEzMTEwOUZCQzBGNzcyRUVCQ0NGN0Q2NkU2Q0M3OTY2MkVDRjg1RTQ1OTc4NUZFNjk5RjlDQzc3Q0U5QzM5RTdEQ0I5Qzc5RTFDRTZCRjYzODc4OUZERTQ3RkVFRkQyRURDNThCRDZGRENCRUZGRURDRkY3Q0U1RkJERjVDRUM1MUIzQzFGN0VGOTFCMUY3OTk2Q0ZCMTNGRjdBM0M3RkY1RUJBRjZGQkE5RjdCRTdCRjZFNDI3NEY5RDM4M0ZGQjNDRjNDQUM3QUY5RUJEQzY3Q0VFREQ3RjE0OUI0MzY3NkUxNDlERTAzRTc3RUFCMzE3REZGQ0RBOUVFNzRGN0Y5RUNFODQwOUJDN0ZGOTU3QTZEQTRBREY4REZCRkFDREJGOEZCRjdFQzU5OEQwRkJGMkY3N0ZFNkU0QTRGMTZCMUY1QzA3NUFFRDk5MUI4RDlCRDBGQjcwNjMxODRGQkY3NDQxMTAyRkJGRkJDRENEM0IwRjNDMTBDODlDQUVDRjFCRTc3RUYwQkNBNTM2MURCOERGRkFFODI3MTE5Rjc4RkIyQTFCRDEzRkI2NUFGRUYzRjAzMURBREI5Q0Y5RThFOTYxMjlCNzQxNjMxODlFRjE3MjZEQjAxM0FEMTgzQkMxNjNFRThCQjgzMTBGRTlCNDEwNUE5M0Y5RUFDN0JCNDI0N0ZFQUEwNDcxNkVGNjk2ODZFOTAyNkRFODEyMDIyNzUzNDYwRjcyQjM5NEYyMUVEODc0NTU5QkE2MDYxQzRGNzQ4QjIyNjVENzFFRTQ0NjBGMDkxM0Q4ODhFNTY5OTgyMjY1RjcxMkUxQTY2QjFEMkVCOEJDMjYyRDlEOEREOUEzNTU1MTIyREM5Q0NGRDU3RTlEODhCOTY2MzJDMjgyRTQxMTZFNDI4QjcxNjI2QjI2QjI0MzgyODJEQ0M0OUFCOTMxMTI5RENGQUQyNzczRDMwQTMwOEE5NkY0OEZCRjFFQ0VCRUQ4Q0M4REZCNTM4RkNFODNBRDA5Mzc2RDJDNTMzOUZCRTkyRjdEQjhCNTY5RTgzNDBDRTQ3QzExRTMyRTk4NzhCM0RFMzgzRTVDMkM1QkQzMzk3Q0I4OTk0QzNDRTdCMjlBQjlDMzFDQUQyRkNBNkJCRDcwRTY4QjNFNzZEMjNBN0NCOEJEQjg3MzJFNjVFRDdBMTMxRTFFOThERThBOTA3MzQxREI3QUY1NjY0N0MyMERGRDgxRTk0REQyMDk3N0FFNjhCMTUyQkQ3NUJBNzEzMEU3NzI5Rjk1NzI2M0Q2RTVFMDdFOEREQzY0MENDQUE0MEEyMTUwOTA1QkU1MzI1NUNGNzQ3Q0YyOTFDNTBEN0JFQkY0NDU4OTVEMDgwNjY5RENDMDRENTU4NEIzOTdDNENDNEEyNTBBQjBEMjg3N0M0MjE1OUZGMDA0OThCRjNBMkM3N0UyRTIyNjI2OTE1NzRBMUZGNDQ4MEI2ODY5QjE4QTY2NzgwM0IyRkQ1NjdBNjI0Q0I5OTE2QUFFNURFMUE2MjM2NTA5N0E4MEMzMkE3MjM5MjU3Njg5QzFBNEVENTkxQzdGRTU5MkIxMzQ3OTE2QUQxQTI0OTdCOEIxNTdDRDVFNzE5OTNGMDUyNkQ4QTcwNjIyNzMwMjgyQzI0ODU1NzhBNjI3Njg3QzlGNjdBMDJDMzdBNkFDODE0MThGNTVBQzQxQzE5MDNDMUM0QzRDODlCNkE3QjEyNDk4RTdCNkNDOTc4MUFCNEI1NkQ2MzI5NzY4RTkyREFEOEM5Njk0MERFMzUxM0FDQkRENTRFRkFBMUFDMEE0MDFFNzFGQTBCODI2RDY1MEZFNEUwRkJCQTI0OUEwQTlERUY0QThCNDc3NDQ2RDA0Njg3NkVBQzQyRjYxRDYwMUJGMzlFNTk2QkY2M0M5OUE2NkVGNTQ3REUyNENGOTE4MjA5RUIxMTM0RkExQzg4OTM4REI0QzE2ODgyOEI4NzY0RkIxQjgzMEQ2MTFCREY1RTVDQjA4MEIzMTAyRDBDQjNCRDVBOUNCOTZEQjBFNThGRkE2NzY4RTMxQTJEOTk2NUJGRUE4N0FDMDhFODAwOEY0QjlFNTk2RTdERjQzNjEyNDQwQjlGQkNBODYxQkRCOTA3QjFBRTE0NkJBODA0RTNBRDk3MENCOTM3MEE0OEYxODYzNDQ5RjFCNkUxNUI1NzJDNUExMTEwMzJGRUM3M0MzQUQyMkUyNTAwRkI4MTA3NERFNEVDNDdEMjhDRTY0MUIwRjUyNjY4NkJCRkI5NzYzN0QzNTRFN0JEQkQ4NDlCOTg4Mzg2RUY4NzBDRjFCNkU4RTVGODVFREUxOEVGNkZDRTI4NjFCQjdBREVDMjY5NkRBRUMxOTdBNkJERkZDOEZENDA2RUU1QzFENzFGRjY0RTUxMUI3RTdCQzVDRjhBMTFDM0Q1QjZFRkIxNkY4MjA0Mjk0MjNGMUI3MjQyN0MwNUExOEQ0RUZDMUE4OEU3MDlCRTQ5RTFCMjA2NTM4MzYzQTQ5MEQ0NTIyQ0VFMEI0QUNBNURCNzhGRTYyNTA2RTk0Njk3RTY5MTU4OEIwQjUxMEEyNjk4Qjk3MUZEMkUxRDg0RDM2Q0Q2NEE2N0VBMjMzMUZCN0U4QTkzM0E1N0E0MDlDNTYwOUQ5RTI3NDg1QzAxQ0M2Qjg1NzY0RTZGRkZDMjVCRDhBODc0REM2RThFN0VCM0UxMjhDNjNDODU5OUI2NEREODkyNTI1MzAyODgwOTZBRkI0OTE2MjgyNkI5M0U0OTVENjFBRjQzQzM3RDY2OTg1MEU4MkFERjIzNjA1REFBQTY0MTAzN0VENjlBQzUxMjU0ODk2OTcwNUYxNkZFODUyNUQ1MzA2QTM3MjRBRDlEQzMxMDBDNDhCMjVFQUNDRDM0QUI4RkU1M0FGNTI0NzA2RDdFRThEQ0EwMDU4MEFENjM0Nzc0REMxMkZEOEE0QTUwMjUyOUVFQThEQjBFQ0JFOUNGNDA4Mjg3MkVFN0VDN0MwMUZDMzk0QjMyRkRBOUQyRDhGM0Y3MDdEREZDMDMwMTgzMUEwOTM1QkI5NEU2REZDRDM1MzJEMDQ3RjUwNzVGMDVFNkUxQjFCMjM2NjRERTk5QUZEMTQzM0U4QzIzNEIwNzVGOUE1RUE1REQ5NjY2RThEOEE3RkVDMEVBRDlFNTUxMTE5NzU3RkQwQkZGNDgxOTYyQURCOTY2MzhEQTBERTAxMUFGRjJCQUE1NDIyNzlBMTA4QjU0NjZFNjYyOEU3NUIzOEFENTdDQTVEMkRCMkFFOTRCQjVBRjc1QjI5QjdFRTcxNjBFMkRFRjhEQkJGN0I4NkI2QzRDOTk2RUJDMzJCRDUxQjUxQzREREVEOUVFOTUwOTlBRDczM0NBMEI4NzMwNzdFQjNERTRBMjlCQTQ3MjYxMzM5RUM3Qjg0NkVGNkFENThEOTFGMjhDN0Q2NDc3NUJGNDIzMUE3NTk2RkZERkUyMDc3MUQzMTQ2QjlGQjU2NzU5NDY2NkU4QjdCODY3RTEzQTRBOEIwNjA4RENEREM2OEEzOEMzMDVDQThBOEFFODkzOUMxNDJDODE5RTFENjBERDA3MTVGQUEyOEYxMjk1RjMxOEY3MDdCRUVDOTU1NDVDRDM1NzA3NjFFRTE2NjQ4QTVGQTIzNkVERDNCN0IwRTcyNUIyNUIxQUY0Mzk0RkJFM0E5REVFRjA4NzIyM0I5NURGQTcwRDZCNEFBOTY2MzU3NzZBQUM5MjU1REM1Qjk3OUQ5N0U0QjU2OTVDNzAzMkQzN0U1M0MxOTE2NzE0MzYzNTc3ODk2NTQ4MjMwMEY1RDhFMDJERDc5MkMyQ0U1QjYzRDJBQ0ZEODlBRTQ0MzY5QkYzQzZEQkEzQkQ3ODExQjc0Q0UyMDJCNjg2MTlEOUVERjE3RTNFRkYwRDNGNkQzRThENjZGMEFGQTcwQUJFRTkxNUVGQkEyQjI4NUY1OTM5OUE3NzM2MDM1RjgwQkI4Njk2MUJGQ0Y3REI2RUEwNjJBMzc4MDdFRjdBNjlENUNEQkVFQzNEQ0MyMUJCQTlCREVFOTdDRDA5NTYyNzY2RTAyMDg1QzJERUM1N0U1MUJDMjNEMTk1NUU2RDFGN0JBRDkzRUI4QUJFMjA1MUExQzJBRjc3RkJBMzE5QTRGRjQxRUU4QUEwMDAwMDAwMDQ5NDU0RTQ0QUU0MjYwODI=",
      "cretDt": "06-19-2013 12:16:25",
      "state": 6002,
      "stateName": "Approved"
    }
}
```

Where is the array ?

Can some one help me hot to get the byte[] again on my browser .

Answer (score 4):

Your data are there, they're just encoded as [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for performance reasons (take a look to [this comparison](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/02/07/json-net-performance-with-binary-data.aspx)). What you pay for that is the overhead needed to decode it in the client (but you'll save *a lot* of bandwidth and then time).

I strongly suggest you keep them in that format (because it's much more compact than the *plain JSON array* representation). You can decode them in JavaScript using a simple library to encode/decode base64. For example [this one](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html).

If you **really** need to serialize your array in that way then change your serialization library (for example [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples) serializes them in the way you need) or to customize library you're using. For example FlexJSON to customize serialization has a powerful mechanism called [Transformers](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/). Just write your own tranformer to override default `ArrayTransformer` behavior for `byte[]` implementing the same logic of `IterableTransformer` and you'll be done.

**Edit**
In your fiddle you're decoding to a string, algorithm isn't different to decode to an array, let's start to change decode function to this:

```
decode : function (input) {
  var output = [];

  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i += 4) {
    a = this._keyStr.indexOf(input[i]);
    b = this._keyStr.indexOf(input[i + 1]);
    c = this._keyStr.indexOf(input[i + 2]);
    d = this._keyStr.indexOf(input[i + 3]);


    output.push((a << 2) | (b >> 4));
    output.push(((b & 15) << 4) | (c >> 2));
    output.push(((c & 3) << 6) | (d & 63));
  }

  return output;
}
```

Please note that this is just an example to **explain the algorithm**, it **doesn't perform any check**, it **doesn't remove padding** and it's even **terribly slow**. A more decent solution would allocate the full array before (or to use an `ArrayBuffer`) because final array size can be computed from input string length. [Look here](https://github.com/niklasvh/base64-arraybuffer) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Solution_.232_.E2.80.93_rewriting_atob%28%29_and_btoa%28%29_using_TypedArrays_and_UTF-8) for complete implementation.

Comment: You can tell it is Base64 due to the use of only letters and the final `=`.

Comment: @SJuan76 well, yes and no. It's a **padding character** so it may not be there (but I admit it's the first thing I check when I see such strings).

Comment: Ok So I got that, when I decoded that string using the JS it returned me junk characters . How can I get the byte[] from this string. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/K4jMg/

Comment: @NullPointerException I added a small example (do not forget to convert uint8 to Java's signed bytes!)

Comment: There are built-in base64 routines in browsers other than IE<10.

Comment: @Pointy they work with strings, not with arrays. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Solution_.232_.E2.80.93_rewriting_atob()_and_btoa()_using_TypedArrays_and_UTF-8) for arrays.